# npmrc, gitconfig & bowerrc with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a node application which uses `npm` and `bower`. Since i am behind a corporate proxy, i need to configure proxy details for `npm`, `git` and `bower` respectively in `.npmrc`, `.gitconfig` and `.bowerrc`.

Currently i am trying to setup Jenkins for continuous integration and want to configure all proxy details inside Jenkins itself ( without accessing any user directories for configuration files)

There is an option to maintain `.npmrc` files inside managed files section of Jenkins but there is no option for `.gitconfig` & `.bowerrc`. Is there any way to configure them ?

Comment: i'm not sure how to do exactly what you're asking. another option would be to commit them directly to your project's source control at the root or copy them from another location in source control to the workspace root directory (rather than your jenkins user home directory). this works for `.npmrc` and `.bowerrc`. `git config --local user.name "your-username"`, etc, might allow you to avoid a .gitconfig file entirely, though you can also shove stuff in `$WORKSPACE/.git/config`.